# table alignment question

Tags: tables

I have a table that currently looks like this:

[image]

Code

```
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Muuntajan nimellisarvot ja ylajannitepuolelta mitatut arvot}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\toprule

Nimellisarvot & Tyhjakayntikoe & Oikosulkukoe \\
\midrule
$S_N=\SI{1000}{\kV\A}$ & $U_0=U_{N1}$ & $U_k=\SI{360}{\V}$ \\
$U_{N1}=\SI{6000}{V}$ & $I_0=\SI{1.67}{\ampere}$ & $I_k=I_{N1}$ \\
$U_{N2}=\SI{400}{\volt}$ & $P_0=\SI{1550}{\watt}$ & $P_k=\SI{8200}{\W}$ \\
$f_N=\SI{50}{\hertz}$ & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can i align my expressions neatly. I want the "equals" sign to be centered

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope I have understood... Something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Muuntajan nimellisarvot ja ylajannitepuolelta mitatut arvot}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{2pt}}c@{\hspace{2pt}}lr@{\hspace{2pt}}c@{\hspace{2pt}}lr@{\hspace{2pt}}c@{\hspace{2pt}}l}
\toprule

\multicolumn{3}{l}{Nimellisarvot} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Tyhjakayntikoe} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Oikosulkukoe} \\
\midrule
$S_N$&$=$&$\SI{1000}{\kV\A}$ & $U_0$&$=$&$U_{N1}$ & $U_k$&$=$&$\SI{360}{\V}$ \\
$U_{N1}$&$=$&$\SI{6000}{V}$ & $I_0$&$=$&$\SI{1.67}{\ampere}$ & $I_k$&$=$&$I_{N1}$ \\
$U_{N2}$&$=$&$\SI{400}{\volt}$ & $P_0$&$=$&$\SI{1550}{\watt}$ & $P_k$&$=$&$\SI{8200}{\W}$ \\
$f_N$&$=$&$\SI{50}{\hertz}$ & &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is another way of aligning content using some `\phantom` and `l`eft over`lap`ping:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,mathtools,siunitx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{booktabs,mathtools,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Nimellisarvot} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Tyhjakayntikoe} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Oikosulkukoe} \\
  \midrule
  $\phantom{U_{N2}}\mathllap{S_N} = \SI{1000}{\kV\A}$ & 
    $U_0 = U_{N1}$ & $U_k = \SI{360}{\V}$ \\
  $U_{N1} = \SI{6000}{V}$ & 
    $\phantom{U_0}\mathllap{I_0} = \SI{1.67}{\ampere}$ & $\phantom{U_k}\mathllap{I_k} = I_{N1}$ \\
  $U_{N2} = \SI{400}{\volt}$ & 
    $\phantom{U_0}\mathllap{P_0} = \SI{1550}{\watt}$ & $\phantom{U_k}\mathllap{P_k} = \SI{8200}{\W}$ \\
  $\phantom{U_{N2}}\mathllap{f_N}=\SI{50}{\hertz}$ & &  \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```